# Vectorize the assignment of a column in a pandas dataframe where a custom index has many rows and the column value is set using all rows in the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I cannot share the actual data so I have made up a similar situation using student courses.
In the real data there are 6 possible statuses.  I have cut it down to 3 here.  I have approximately 300k rows and am expecting this to grow by 100x soon.
I need to set a value in a column based upon the evaluation of another column across multiple rows that share an index.
I can do this using iteration or a lambda function but they both take over 5 minutes on a Mac (it will be 10x faster at least when deployed to Linux) to run and when my data is increased, neither solutions will not be an option.  I need to find out how to vectorize this.

Data snippet:

```
d = [{'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.course_status = ''
# Create a tuple so the student and course can be tracked as one index:
df['name_course'] = df[['name', 'course']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
# Set the tuple as the index (hoping to get a bit of performance boost)
df = df.set_index(['name_course'],drop=True)
```

| name_course | name | course | exam_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Absent |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Absent |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Absent |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass |

Both of these coding techniques below work but basically iterate over the unique student/course tuple and with hundreds of millions of rows will be too slow:

Approach 1: Iteration using a unique index which greatly cuts down on the loop count because there are about 50-150 rows for each index in the full data. However, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the multiple loc commands in the script.  I cannot use an 'at' because there are multiple rows returned by loc.  At any case, if I could do that, it would only make it as fast as the lambda approach.

```
for i in df.index.unique():
    status_list = list(df.loc[[i]]['exam_status'])
    if 'Fail' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Fail'
    elif 'Absent' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Absent'
    elif 'Pass' or 'Skip' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Pass'
print(df.to_markdown())
```

print(df.to_markdown())

| name_course | name | course | exam_status | course_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Math') | Student1 | Math | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Chemistry') | Student1 | Chemistry | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Absent | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Absent | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Art') | Student1 | Art | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student1', 'Computer Science') | Student1 | Computer Science | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Math') | Student2 | Math | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Chemistry') | Student2 | Chemistry | Absent | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Pass | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Art') | Student2 | Art | Fail | Fail |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass | Pass |
| ('Student2', 'Computer Science') | Student2 | Computer Science | Pass | Pass |

Approach 2: Using a lambda instead.  This works faster due to the lack of multiple loc commands inside the function, but still does not use vectorization and is quite slow.

```
# Set course_status based on rule statuses for that audit
def set_course_status(i):
    status_list = list(df.loc[[i]]['exam_status'])
    if 'Fail' in status_list: return 'Fail'
    elif 'Absent' in status_list: return 'Absent'
    elif 'Pass' in status_list: return 'Pass'
df['course_status'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x : set_course_status(x.name))
```

The results are the same as above.

Can anyone please come up with a way to do this using vectorization or some really fast method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def addCourseStatus(df):
    has=pd.DataFrame({'absent':df.exam_status=='Absent', 'fail':df.exam_status=='Fail', 'pas':df.exam_status=='Pass'}).groupby(level=0).any()
    df.loc[has.fail,'course_status']='Fail'
    df.loc[~has.fail & has.absent, 'course_status']='Absent'
    df.loc[~has.fail & ~has.absent & has.pas, 'course_status']='Pass'
```

Probably not optimal. I don't like the creation of a temporary dataframe. But vectorized.

It is faster, but barely (some 30% faster) than your two solutions for your example. Because it is vectorized indeed, but that are a few of those vectorized operations (3 comparisons, then the creation of the dataframe, then 3 booleans/loc operations).

But the more rows there will be, the more the vectorization will show, and the less those 7 operations will matter.

Comment: Thank you chrslg.  i left a comment on the second answer that applies to both because I did not see a general comment section.  I will be testing both answers.  I really appreciate the help.  

(*Like*) But the more rows there will be, the more the vectorization will show, and the less those 7 operations will matter.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. It changes `df` in place. So now, your `df` has a `course_status` column. Exactly like your own code does.

Comment: This is truly amazing.  My old code ran in 5+ min (that was the lambda which was the faster of the two).  This ran in 2/10th of a second.  I had to look to make sure it actually did anything because it was so fast.  TY :)

312629 rows × 20 columns

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```py
import pandas as pd


d = [{'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student1', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Math', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Chemistry', 'exam_status':'Absent'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Art', 'exam_status':'Fail'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},
     {'name':'Student2', 'course':'Computer Science', 'exam_status':'Pass'},]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.course_status = ''
# Create a tuple so the student and course can be tracked as one index:
df['name_course'] = df[['name', 'course']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
# Set the tuple as the index (hoping to get a bit of performance boost)
df = df.set_index(['name_course'],drop=True)

# ordering of statuses
status_map = {"Fail": 0, "Absent": 1, "Pass": 2}
# map statuses to numeric
df["course_status"] = df.exam_status.map(status_map)
# get the min course_status per name_course
df["course_status"] = df.groupby([
    "name_course",
]).course_status.transform("min").map(
    # map back to original status names
    {v: k for k, v in status_map.items()}
)

print(df)
```

```
                                  name            course exam_status course_status
name_course                                                                       
(Student1, Math)              Student1              Math        Pass          Fail
(Student1, Math)              Student1              Math        Fail          Fail
(Student1, Math)              Student1              Math        Pass          Fail
(Student1, Chemistry)         Student1         Chemistry        Pass          Pass
(Student1, Chemistry)         Student1         Chemistry        Pass          Pass
(Student1, Chemistry)         Student1         Chemistry        Pass          Pass
(Student1, Art)               Student1               Art      Absent          Fail
(Student1, Art)               Student1               Art      Absent          Fail
(Student1, Art)               Student1               Art        Fail          Fail
(Student1, Computer Science)  Student1  Computer Science        Fail          Fail
(Student1, Computer Science)  Student1  Computer Science        Fail          Fail
(Student1, Computer Science)  Student1  Computer Science        Pass          Fail
(Student2, Math)              Student2              Math        Pass          Pass
(Student2, Math)              Student2              Math        Pass          Pass
(Student2, Math)              Student2              Math        Pass          Pass
(Student2, Chemistry)         Student2         Chemistry        Fail          Fail
(Student2, Chemistry)         Student2         Chemistry        Pass          Fail
(Student2, Chemistry)         Student2         Chemistry      Absent          Fail
(Student2, Art)               Student2               Art        Pass          Fail
(Student2, Art)               Student2               Art        Pass          Fail
(Student2, Art)               Student2               Art        Fail          Fail
(Student2, Computer Science)  Student2  Computer Science        Pass          Pass
(Student2, Computer Science)  Student2  Computer Science        Pass          Pass
(Student2, Computer Science)  Student2  Computer Science        Pass          Pass
```

## Time comparisons via %%timeit

```py
# your first attempt
%%timeit
for i in df.index.unique():
    status_list = list(df.loc[[i]]['exam_status'])
    if 'Fail' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Fail'
    elif 'Absent' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Absent'
    elif 'Pass' or 'Skip' in status_list: df.loc[[i], 'course_status']  = 'Pass'
```

```
8.62 ms ± 1.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
# your second attempt
%%timeit
# Set course_status based on rule statuses for that audit
def set_course_status(i):
    status_list = list(df.loc[[i]]['exam_status'])
    if 'Fail' in status_list: return 'Fail'
    elif 'Absent' in status_list: return 'Absent'
    elif 'Pass' in status_list: return 'Pass'
df['course_status'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x : set_course_status(x.name))
```

```
6.79 ms ± 561 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
# my attempt
%%timeit
# ordering of statuses
status_map = {"Fail": 0, "Absent": 1, "Pass": 2}
# map statuses to numeric
df["course_status"] = df.exam_status.map(status_map)
# get the min course_status per name_course
df["course_status"] = df.groupby([
    "name_course",
]).course_status.transform("min").map(
    # map back to original status names
    {v: k for k, v in status_map.items()}
)
```

```
1.99 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

## Testing on 10,000x the rows

```py
# 240_000 rows instead of 24
big = pd.concat((df for _ in range(10_000)))
```

```py
# NOTE: I swapped `df` for `big`
%%timeit
# ordering of statuses
status_map = {"Fail": 0, "Absent": 1, "Pass": 2}
# map statuses to numeric
big["course_status"] = big.exam_status.map(status_map)
# get the min course_status per name_course
big["course_status"] = big.groupby([
    "name_course",
]).course_status.transform("min").map(
    # map back to original status names
    {v: k for k, v in status_map.items()}
)
```

```
33.7 ms ± 1.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: The problem is the `lambda`. As soon as you have a lambda, in a map, or an apply, you more or less fall back in the same problem as a for loop. The only difference is the for loop itself (the iterations are done in pandas C code, not in python code). But each iteration is a call to pure python function, one by one. So, that cost a lot. Exactly like OP's second solution. That being said, the same idea (transforming status into a number, then `.groupby`/`min`, then transforming back into strings, could be implemented without lambda.

Comment: @chrslg -- noted. `lambda` removed 

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I cannot believe how fast people got back to me.  I was hoping for something within a few weeks.  I am new at these submissions.  Also, I don't really know where to put comments so sorry if I am doing this wrong.  I will test both of thse answers with my data and let you know which is working best.  I do want to focus on a solution that doesn't grow by time in a linear fashion with more data since I know it is coming.

TY TY TY TY TY TY TY

Comment: I also tested this code and it also completed 312629 rows in 2/10 of a second.  Thanks you @IanThompson :)
I'm not sure which one to vote up as the best so I think I will wait until I process 100x data and come back to give the results.
This is amazing.  Thanks to IanThompson and chrslg.  Both solutions gave me what I asked for which was vectorization.  I did not think they would work this fast though.

Comment: @Etbme -- only one can be selected as the answer, but you can always upvote both ;)

Comment: Update: I plan to use answer 1 for this project because I did not mention that I need the ability to add conditions, eg:

has=pd.DataFrame({
'absent':df.exam_status=='Absent', 
'fail':df.exam_status=='Fail', 
'pas':df.exam_status=='Pass',
'exc':df.exam_status=='Exception',
}).groupby(level=0).any()
    
 df.loc[~has.fail & ~has.absent & (has.pas |  has.exc), 'course_status']='Pass'

However, having said that, I really like the map solution and plan to use that for other code now that I see how mapping works.  So a big thank you again for both solutions.  You guys are awesome.